# Query that returns values where a certain number of rows meet certain condition

Tags: mysql, vb.net, rdlc

I'm trying to make a report and i'm having some dificulty designing a query to show the data i need.

I have 2 tables:

```
+-----------+------------+----------+
+TherapyID  + CostumerID + ClinicID +
+-----------+------------+----------+
+    1      +  John      + Clinic 1 +
+-----------+------------+----------+
+    2      +  Susan     + Clinic 2 +
+-----------+------------+----------+
+    3      +  Mary      + Clinic 3 +
+-----------+------------+----------+


+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------+
+TherapyID  + TherapyLine  + Treatment + Result +
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------+
+     1     +       1      +     A     + Success+
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------+
+     1     +       2      +     B     + Success+
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------+
+     1     +       3      +     C     + Success+
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------+
+     2     +       1      +     A     + Success+
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------+
+     2     +       2      +     B     + Fail   +
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------+
+     2     +       3      +     C     + Success+
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------+
+     3     +       1      +     A     + Success+
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------+
+     3     +       2      +     B     + Success+
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------+
+     3     +       3      +     C     + Fail   +
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------+
```

I need to make a query that shows me only the customers or therapyid's that have successfully received all treatments **A,B,C**

The Query Result should be like this:

```
+------------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+
+ TherapyID  + TherapyLine + Customer +  Clinic + Treatment + Result  +
+------------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+
+     1      +     1       +  John    + Clinic 1+    A      + Success + 
+------------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+
+     1      +     2       +  John    + Clinic 1+    B      + Success +
+------------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+
+     1      +     3       +  John    + Clinic 1+    C      + Success +
+------------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

This was the only therapyid where all treatments **A,B,C** where **Success**
I really don't have any idea on how to query this, what i have tried up to now
allways returns results from **TherapyID** **2,3** where result was **Success** too.
Thx in advance for the help.

Comment: Is it a fancy dress clinic? And consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) of same.

Comment: What if `TheraphyID 1` has a Treatment of `D` which fails in the result, will it be still included on the list as long as it has `A, B, C` and it succeeds?

Comment: No it should return nothing in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.TherapyID,TherapyLine,t1.CostumerID as Customer,Clinic,Treatment, 
Result from table1 t1,table2 t2 where t1.TherapyID =t2.TherapyID and
t2.result='Success' group by customerID having count(customeID)=3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.TherapyID,TherapyLine,CustomerID as Customer,ClinicID as Clinic,Treatment,Result  
FROM FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.TherapyID=t2.TherapyID WHERE CustomerID IN 
(SELECT CustomerID
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.TherapyID=t2.TherapyID AND Result='Success' 
GROUP BY CustomerID 
HAVING COUNT(CustomerID)=3)
```